# Run JavaScript function after another after x Time

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I'm trying to develop a simple animation using SVG and JavaScript. I got a "button" which is running an onclick function to hide the Start button and start the animations.

I'm having issues with a time base function, basically I have "bubble box" which is where some text will appear as if the animation were talking to the user, kind like a dialogue, and after a while that text disappears and a new one appears in its place.

The problem is that after pressing the Start button, the text shows up for half a second and then it disappears. 
It is supposed to appear after the Start button is pressed and then after, 5 seconds for exemple, it disappears again.

this is what I have done so far, everything is inside a SVG tag.

```
 <rect id="startButton" style="cursor:pointer;" x="200" y="150" rx="5" height="25" width="80" fill="white" stroke="white" stroke-width="1" onclick="startAni()"/>
    <text id="startText" style="cursor:pointer;" x="215" y="170" fill="black" onclick="startAni()">START</text>

    <script>
        function startAni(){

            document.getElementById("textLine1").style.display="inline-block";
            document.getElementById("startButton").style.display="none";
            document.getElementById("startText").style.display="none";

            window.setTimeout(function(){textBubble(); 50000})

            function textBubble(){
                document.getElementById("textLine1").style.display="none";

            }

        }
    </script>
```

and this is the "bubble box"

```
<text id="textLine1" x="300" y="175" fill="white">WHY?</text>
```

as for CSS this is what I got in for textLine1

```
#textLine1{
display:none;
```

}

I'm okey with new ideas on how to make this happen but I would like to work with JavaScript, SVG or CSS. JQuery isn't out of the question but as I'm not familiar with it I wouldn't like to use it for now.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: May I suggest you to learn more about callbacks. It should help alot in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Your timer is in the wrong place, more specifically your curly bracket to close the function. Also no need for function thinking about it, just pass in textBubble.

```
window.setTimeout(textBubble, 50000);
```